# rvm ruby install failing setting paths

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've never used Ruby before so this and the surrounding terminology is new to me; I'm only doing the install so I have a base to run a specific application.

I need Ruby 1.9.3, as I understand it I should be using RVM as it'll make things less complicated with version conflicts (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and already seem to have 1.8 & 1.9.1).

Problem is that I'm still getting version conflicts, what am I doing wrong please?

Details follow:

On a vanilla ubuntu 12.04 LTS I install rvm & bundler

`sudo apt-get install ruby-bundler ruby-rvm`

I have a .rvmrc file in my project root containing:

`rvm use 1.9.3-p484@project-root --create`

I have executed 
`sudo rvm reload`

I then tell rvm to install a particular ruby

`sudo rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484`

and it barfs

> Installing rubygems for
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
>
> ERROR: Error
>   running
>   'GEM_PATH="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484:/usr/share/ruby- 
>   rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484:/usr/share/ruby-  rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global"
>   GEM_HOME="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484"
>   "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby"
>   "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/rubygems-1.6.2/setup.rb"', please read
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p484/rubygems.install.lo

The log contains this:

> /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:483:in
>   `find_files': undefined method`map' for Gem::Specification:Class
>   (NoMethodError)
>           from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1108:in
>   `load_plugins'
>           from /var/cache/ruby-rvm/src/rubygems-1.6.2/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:84:in`
>   '
>           from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require'
>           from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`
>   require'
>           from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/rubygems-1.6.2/setup.rb:25:

Looks like some conflict with v1.9.1?

If I go ahead anyway and run `sudo bundle install` (I have a Gemfile with some entries) i get a different error implying that bundler is using ruby 1.8!

> Installing nokogiri (1.6.1)
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in
>   `ensure_required_ruby_version_met': nokogiri requires Ruby version >=
>   1.9.2. (Gem::InstallError)

**What am I doing wrong please?**

The only other salient info I can give is the output from `rvm info` as you can see I have paths empty and the 'binary' is incorrect.

> system:
>
> system:
>       uname:       "Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 15:31:16 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
>       bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
>       zsh:         " => not installed"
>
> rvm:
>       version:      "rvm 1.6.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"
>
> homes:
>       gem:          "not set"
>       ruby:         "not set"
>
> binaries:
>       ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
>       irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
>       gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
>       rake:         ""
>
> environment:
>       PATH:         "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/bin:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/bin"
>       GEM_HOME:     ""
>       GEM_PATH:     ""
>       MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
>       IRBRC:        ""
>       RUBYOPT:      ""
>       gemset:       ""

`/usr/bin/ruby -v` returns 1.8.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the version of RVM that comes with Ubuntu is broken. I deleted it and followed the instructions [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395).